# mixing v9 firebase SDK with compat layer for firebaseUI

Tags: firebase, firebase-authentication

I would like to use firebaseUI to manage my user authentication. Unfortunately the documentation online suggests that I can't use it with the V9 SDK unless I go through the compat layer. If I do this, I have to initialise the firebase app twice, one for the compat layer, and once for the rest of the API:

compat:

```
const compatApp = firebase.initializeApp(firebaseConfig);
const auth = firebase.auth();
```

v9:

```
const app = initializeApp(firebaseConfig);
const firestore = getFirestore(app);
```

I'm not sure whether these two instances will interfere with each other.
Can I use both APIs in the same app? should I just use the compat layer for everything?

My code runs well enough, but I just don't know whether I'm setting myself up for problems later.

I followed the firebase official documentation here:
https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/web/firebaseui

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

I found my answer in:
https://firebase.google.com/docs/web/modular-upgrade

> Using the compat libraries during upgrade allows you to continue using
> version 8 code alongside code refactored for version 9. This means you
> can keep existing version 8 code for Cloud Firestore while you
> refactor Authentication or other Firebase SDK code to the version 9
> style, and still successfully compile your app with both code styles.
> The same is true for version 8 and version 9 code within a product
> such as Cloud Firestore; new and old code styles can coexist, as long
> as you are importing the compat packages

So it looks like I can use the compat packages for firebaseUI, though it does mean the SDK will be a little bloated.